# Picking Numbers - Solve Hacker Rank challenge in Ruby

Tags: ruby

## PROBLEM Explanation

Given an array of integers, find the longest subarray where the absolute difference between any two elements is less than or equal to 1.

Example
a = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]
There are two subarrays meeting the criterion: [1,1,2,2] and [4,4,5,5,5]. The maximum length subarray has 5 elements.

pickingNumbers has the following parameter(s):

- int a[n]: an array of integers

Returns

- int: the length of the longest subarray that meets the criterion

### WHAT I have tried

```
def pickingNumbers(a)
    # Write your code here
    a.sort!
    current_counter = 0
    max_counter = 0
    
    i = 0
    while i < a.size
      j = 1
      
      while (a[j].to_int - a[i].to_int) <= 1
        current_counter += 1
        j += 1
        max_counter = current_counter if current_counter > max_counter
      end
      
      i+=1
    end
    max_counter
end

input = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]
pickingNumbers(input)
```

### Requested:

Why above code didn't work? I would appreciate it if someone can explain.
I am learning to solve algorithmic challenges and I know there are dozens of better solutions. Still, I would like to know why exactly this code is not working!))
Thanks in advance

Comment: `undefined method 'to_int' for nil:NilClass` for the reason explained by Matthew here below. Tip for the algorithm: take a look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally

Comment: "Why above code didn't work?" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the Hackerrank problem? If my understanding is correct, you want a *subarray* of `a`, which is an array of the form `a[i..j]`, so I don't see how you can sort `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking to make sure `i < a.size` but you aren't doing the same for `j`.

Eventually you increment j beyond the size of the array and try to access `a[9]` which returns nil.

`nil.to_int` is causing the error (although you didn't actually state what error you were seeing in your question).

The more [idiomatic](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops) way of iterating through an array in Ruby is using `.each` which avoids this class of errors.

I would also advise against using `.sort!` on the parameter you passed in. The `!` bang operator on the end warns you that this is modifying the original array.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the way to solve it with more time complexity that avoids using 2 loops

*I know that there are few modifications that can be made (like using the ternary operator and so on). You are welcome to cement if you have one in your mind*

```
def pickingNumbers(a)
    # Write your code here
    a.sort!
    current_counter = 1
    max_counter = 0
    reference_checker = a[0]
    
    i = 1
    while i < a.size
    
      if (a[i] - reference_checker) <= 1
        current_counter += 1
      else
        reference_checker = a[i]
        max_counter = current_counter if current_counter > max_counter
        current_counter = 1
      end
      
      i+=1
    end
    if current_counter < max_counter
      max_counter
    else
      current_counter
    end
end

input = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]
p pickingNumbers(input)
```

> Credits to my stand-up team)

Comment: `pickingNumbers [1,1,3,2,4,4,5,5,7,6,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,7,8] #=> 7`, but I don't see a qualifying subarray of size greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to solve the problem, one is easy to code, the other is more complex but I expect it should be faster, possibly much faster. Both use the following arrays for demonstration.

```
a1 = [1,1,2,3,4]
a2 = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]
a3 = [1,1,3,2,4,4,5,5,7,6,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,7,8]
```

**Not much code, but may be fast enough**

```
def quick_n_dirty(arr)
  arr.size.downto(1).each do |n|
    arr.each_index.each_cons(n) do |a|
      mn, mx = a.map { |i| arr[i] }.minmax
      return { start: a.first, end: a.last } if mx <= mn + 1
    end
  end
end
```

```
quick_n_dirty(a1)
  #=> {:start=>0, :end=>2}
quick_n_dirty(a2)
  #=> {:start=>4, :end=>8}
quick_n_dirty(a3)
  #=> {:start=>4, :end=>7}
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Consider `a1`, which contains five elements. First see if the entire array meets the requirement, in which case we would be finished:

```
enum = a1.each_cons(5)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]:each_cons(5)>
```

To see the elements that will be generated by `enum` we can convert it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

It generates just one element, `a1` itself:

```
a = enum.next
  #=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b, c = a.minmax 
  #=> [1, 4]
```

As `(c-b).abs = 3` and `3 > 1` we see that `a1` does not meet the requirement. Now consider all subarrays of size `4`. If one is found having the desired property we are finished.

```
enum = a1.each_cons(4)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]:each_cons(4)>
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
a = enum.map { |arr| arr.minmax }
  #=> [[1, 3], [1, 4]]
b = a.map { |x,y| (y-x).abs }
  #=> [2, 3]
b.find { |diff| diff <= 1 }
   #=> nil
```

This tells us there is no subarray of size `4` that meets the requirement, so we continue looking at subarrays of size `3`:

```
enum = a1.each_cons(3)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]:each_cons(3)>
enum.to_a
  #=> [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
a = enum.map { |arr| arr.minmax }
  #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
b = a.map { |x,y| (y-x).abs }
  #=> [1, 2, 2]
b.find { |diff| diff <= 1 }
  #=> 1
```

[Pay dirt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pay-dirt)! We find that the subarray `[1, 1, 2]` meets the requirement, so we are finished!

This is what my code does except it returns a hash showing the beginning and end of the (or I should say "a", rather than "the", as there may be ties) largest subarray with the desired property. (On re-reading the question it appears that only the length of the largest subarray is needed, permitting a minor simplification.)

If `n = arr.size`, in the worst case, the number of subarrays that must examined equals `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1`, which equals `n*(n+1)/2`.

**More code but it should be faster**

```
def should_be_faster(arr)
  a = arr + [Float::INFINITY]
  current = { early: 0, late: nil }
  a.each_with_index.with_object({ start: 0, end: 0 }) do |(n,i), longest|
    next if i.zero?               
    curr_val = a[i]
    curr_early_val = a[current[:early]]
    curr_late_val = current[:late].nil? ? nil : a[current[:late]]
    if current[:late].nil?
      case curr_val - curr_early_val
      when 0
      when 1, -1
        current[:late] = i
      else
        update_if_improvement(current, longest, i)
        current[:early] = i
        current[:late] = nil
      end
    elsif curr_val != curr_early_val && curr_val != curr_late_val
      update_if_improvement(current, longest, i)
      if (curr_val - curr_late_val).abs == 1
        current[:early] = current[:late]
        current[:late] = i
      else
        current[:early] = i
        current[:late] = nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
def update_if_improvement(current, longest, i)
  if i - current[:early] > longest[:end] - longest[:start] + 1
    longest[:start] = current[:early]
    longest[:end] = i-1
  end
end
```

```
should_be_faster(a1)
  #=> {:start=>0, :end=>2}
should_be_faster(a2)
  #=> {:start=>4, :end=>8}
should_be_faster(a3)
  #=> {:start=>4, :end=>7}
```

Comment: I will provide an explanation to solution #2 as time permits.

Answer (score -1):

I have a routine that will split the array into groups, so that [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] will be 2 arrays [1,1,1,2,2,2] and [3,3,3]

obviously if this was for hackerrank, you'll need to see if it's quick enough.

if you want an awful one liner:

```
a.sort.inject({}) {|x,y| x.key?(y-1) ? x[y-1] << y : (x[y]||=[] ; x[y] << y) ; x}.values.map(&:count).max
```

or as a longer procedure:

```
def pickingNumbers(a)
  # sort the array and work through the array with an accumulator
  newh = a.sort.each_with_object({}) do |value, acc|
    # check if we had a previous value
    if acc.key?(value - 1)
      # push the current value into the array for the previous value
      acc[value - 1] << value
    else
      # make sure that the "acc[value]" is an array
      acc[value] ||= []
      # push the current value into the value for the current value
      acc[value] << value
    end
  end

  # get the size of all of the values in the newly created hash
  vals = newh.values.map(&:count)

  # return the maximum of that array
  vals.max
end

input = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]
pickingNumbers(input)
```